# Not getting any webhook notification for Microsoft O365 Management APIs

Tags: office365api, azure-management-api

I have created the below webhooks and all are enabled.:

```
[
    {
        "contentType": "Audit.AzureActiveDirectory",
        "status": "enabled",
        "webhook": {
            "authId": "12345",
            "address": "https://978b7cfb66d9.ngrok.io/callback/",
            "expiration": "",
            "status": "enabled"
        }
    },
    {
        "contentType": "Audit.General",
        "status": "enabled",
        "webhook": {
            "authId": "12345",
            "address": "https://978b7cfb66d9.ngrok.io/callback/",
            "expiration": "",
            "status": "enabled"
        }
    },
    {
        "contentType": "Audit.SharePoint",
        "status": "enabled",
        "webhook": {
            "authId": "12345",
            "address": "https://978b7cfb66d9.ngrok.io/callback/",
            "expiration": "",
            "status": "enabled"
        }
    }
]
```

I don't see any notifications coming when there are changes made in sharepoint. Anything in particular need to change?
From the access token, I do see correct app permissions:

```
"roles": [
    "ServiceHealth.Read",
    "ActivityFeed.Read"
  ]
```

I manually queried to get content and it shows empty.

```
https://manage.office.com/api/v1.0/{tenant-guid}/activity/feed/subscriptions/content?contentType=Audit.Sharepoint
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the auditing for Office 365 organization is disabled.

Make sure you turn on [audit log search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/turn-audit-log-search-on-or-off?view=o365-worldwide).